# After hiding the windows form not able to show it back

Tags: c#, .net

Below is my code. Here you can see that i am using constant for hide/show the window. Hide the other application from the another application in C#.net.

```
    private const int SW_HIDE = 0;
    private const int SW_SHOW = 5;

    [DllImport("User32")]
    private static extern int ShowWindow(int hwnd, int nCmdShow);

    private void btnHide_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){

        Process[] processRunning = Process.GetProcesses();
        foreach (Process pr in processRunning){

            if (pr.ProcessName == FileName){
                hWnd = pr.MainWindowHandle.ToInt32();
                ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_HIDE);
            }
        }
    }

    private void btnShow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){

        Process[] processRunning = Process.GetProcesses();

        foreach (Process pr in processRunning){
            if (pr.ProcessName == FileName){

                hWnd = pr.MainWindowHandle.ToInt32();
                ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_SHOW);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: "not able to show it back" what does it mean                                                            
 do you get any error, some code not execution as it should?

Comment: if you show it back, you still need to activate to see it ... in case it is in the background :-)

Comment: So use SW_RESTORE = 9  : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-showwindow

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Restore a minimized window of another application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9099479/restore-a-minimized-window-of-another-application)

Comment: No, i can not get any error, but  'pr.MainWindowHandle' return 0(Zero)?

Answer (score 2):

When visible the MainWindowHandle is non-zero, after the Window is hidden the handle gets set to 0. I haven't found a way yet to get the required handle - maybe a work around would be to maintain a list of the windows you have hidden.

```
List<int> HiddenWindows = new List<int>();

private void btnHide_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  Process[] processRunning = Process.GetProcessesByName(FileName);
  foreach (Process pr in processRunning)
  {
    int hWnd = pr.MainWindowHandle.ToInt32();
    if (hWnd == 0)
      continue;
    ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_HIDE);
    HiddenWindows.Add(hWnd);
  }
}

private void btnShow_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  foreach (int hWnd in HiddenWindows)
  {
    ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_SHOW);
  }
  HiddenWindows.Clear();
}
```

NOTE - rather than iterate through all processes returned by GetProcesses - you can use GetProcessesByName just to get the processes you are interested in.

There is an answer here based on other User32 functions - but seems quite complex : [Unhide process by its process name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25961231/unhide-process-by-its-process-name)

A quick test with a WPF application showed multiple Window handles found using the code in the linked solution - the answer is to remove the return after the call to ShowWindow. I have added a modified version below to reopen multiple application instances if required.

```
private const int SW_SHOW = 5;
private String FileName = "notepad";

[DllImport("User32")]
private static extern int ShowWindow(IntPtr hwnd, int nCmdShow);
[DllImport("User32.dll")]
private static extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(IntPtr hwndParent, IntPtr hwndChildAfter, string strClassName, string strWindowName);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern int GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, out int ProcessId);

private void btnShow2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  //an array of all processes with name "processName"
  Process[] localAll = Process.GetProcessesByName(FileName);

  foreach (var pr in localAll)
  {
    IntPtr hWnd = IntPtr.Zero;
    int prcsId = 0;

    //check all open windows (not only the process we are looking) begining from the
    //child of the desktop, handle = IntPtr.Zero initialy.
    do
    {
      //get child handle of window who's handle is "handle".
      hWnd = FindWindowEx(IntPtr.Zero, hWnd, null, null);
      GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd, out prcsId); //get ProcessId from "handle"

      //if it matches what we are looking
      //Note there maybe multiple Windows found - so try all of them
      if (prcsId == pr.Id)
        ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_SHOW); //Show Window
    } while (hWnd != IntPtr.Zero);
  }
}
```

NOTE that I have modified the ShowWindow definition to use an IntPtr as the type for the Window handle - this is the preferred type to use & it is the actual type of MainWindowHandle. In your hide method just change the code to 
be

```
IntPtr hWnd = pr.MainWindowHandle;
```

or the entire loop to

```
foreach (Process pr in processRunning)
{
  ShowWindow(pr.MainWindowHandle, SW_HIDE);
}
```

Comment: Thank you PaulF. You solution is correct. But in my scenario, i want to close the first application after hiding the another application. And again when i start my first application, i want to show the hidden application.

Comment: Unfortunately, once hidden the application has no window - so the applications MainWindowHandle is set to zero. The answer in the link I added should do the trick - getting the process ID & then a brute force search of all available windows to find the one attached to process matched by ID.

Comment: i try as given in your link,it does not work also i try
ShowWindow(handle, SW_RESTORE); // Restore Windows
ShowWindow(handle, SW_SHOW); //Show Window
SetForegroundWindow(handle);

Comment: @AnkitUpadhyay: I have updated with code that works for me based on the original link code.

Comment: I try on Notepad, that working good, My problem is in some condition the application is start without UI. So without load UI how can i show the UI?

Comment: I don't think I can help on that particular problem - if the application starts up without a UI under normal conditions, how would you get it to display? What was the value of MainWindowHandle when you hid it - it may have been 0 if it had no main window?

Answer (score 0):

This is how `Process.GetProcess()` works.

Once you hide the main window of process its `MainWindowHandle` for next iteration over processes will become `IntPtr.Zero`. It has something to do with how `MainWindowHandle` is retrieved I guess.

Solutions:

1. enumerate processes once
2. store `hWnd` (e.g. in `Dictionary<string, int>`) and call `ShowWindow()` without retrieving processes again.